# Error en directiva: Can't bind to 'disableControl' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-checkbox'

Tags: angular

Tengo el error del titulo al utilizar la directiva asi

```
<mat-checkbox
    name="pool"
    [disableControl]="this.isCheckBoxAble()"
    formControlName="pool"
    >  </mat-checkbox>
```

El .ts del disable control:

```
@Directive({selector: '[disableControl]'})
export class DisableControlDirective {

  @Input() set disableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {}
}
```

En el módulo dónde utilizo la directiva importé el module donde está la directiva.
Además, se lo puse como provider

```
providers: [DisableControlDirective]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asegúrate de que, en el módulo en el que está declarada, has añadido la misma a la lista de `exports`, para que el módulo de tu aplicación tenga acceso a ella.

He creado un escenario donde uso tu código sin problemas: https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-gawtby?file=main.ts